# Google Play Services stopped working after account migration (android)

Tags: android, google-play-games, developer-console

I migrated my working game with its leaderboard implementation from google play services, into another developer account. 
Ever since that migration the google play services library stopped working, saying the app is wrongly configured. 
I made a new Game project in the developer console and entered the SHA1 again, modified the game ids and leaderboard ids on my resources folder. Nothing helps.
Worst part is that i cannot test if i fixed this or not, because the installation from android studio works like a charm, but then the app from the store doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was that i had provided the apk at the google console with the DEBUG SHA1 instead of the RELEASE. Also, after switching and messing around with the accounts and the game projects, the credentials existed on the API console but not on the game project console.
So this was fixed by removing all the API credentials related to the game project, removed the game project from the google games project console and started a new one with the RELEASE SHA1.